# Query to list where a value doesn't exist for a grouping

Tags: sql, select

Looking for a way to report on where an update_code of 'delivery_completed' does not exist for the listing of 'PRO_BILL' in SQL

--sorry very much a newbie--

```
pro_bill    | update_code           | entry_timestamp
PRO0211475  | delivery_arrived      | 6/14/18 12:23
PRO0211475  | delivery_completed    | 6/14/18 12:23
PRO0211475  | pick_up_arrived       | 6/14/18 12:23
PRO0211475  | pick_up_completed     | 6/14/18 12:23
PRO0211510  | pick_up_completed     | 6/14/18 11:52
PRO0211510  | pick_up_arrived       | 6/14/18 11:52
PRO0211510  | delivery_arrived      | 6/14/18 11:52
PRO0211527  | delivery_arrived      | 6/14/18 11:27
PRO0211527  | pick_up_arrived       | 6/14/18 11:27
PRO0211527  | pick_up_completed     | 6/14/18 11:27
```

Ideally, i would like to have the query return (In one line) where the delivery_departed does not exist for that pro_bill

```
Pro_bill | pick_up_arrived | pick_up_completed | delivery_arrived
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want conditional aggregation

```
 SELECT 
   pro_bill,
   MAX( CASE WHEN update_code = 'delivery_arrived' THEN entry_timestamp END) as delivery_arrived,
   MAX( CASE WHEN update_code = 'delivery_completed' THEN entry_timestamp END) as delivery_completed,
   MAX( CASE WHEN update_code = 'pick_up_arrived' THEN entry_timestamp END) as pick_up_arrived,
   MAX( CASE WHEN update_code = 'pick_up_completed' THEN entry_timestamp END) as pick_up_completed
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY pro_bill
```

Comment: Thanks, only need more groupies :)

Comment: Honestly - i spent hours on this and was ready to give up - never even thought to go that route. Thank you very very much... and also for reformatting my first question.

Comment: To format as `code`, select the text and press `ctrl-k`  or add 4 spaces before each line. Remember mark the answer as accepted if solve your problem using the green tick.